# Función para sumar dígitos dentro de una cadena de caracteres en Python (¿Cuál es el error?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, algoritmos

Estoy tratando de armar una función que me permita extraer los dígitos dentro de una cadena de caracteres y regrese como resultado la suma de dichos dígitos. El código que llevo hasta ahora es:

```
def sum_c(x):
    sum=0
    for i in x:
        if i.isdigit():
            sum+= i.isdigit()
    return sum
```

Aplicamos la función a la siguiente cadena:

```
sum_c("1234afkñl21")
```

Obtengo como resultado:

```
Out[14]: 6
```

Por supuesto, el resultado es incorrecto, ya que la suma total debe ser 13. 
He investigado y encontré que existen funciones como re.findall que hacen el trabajo rápidamente. Sin embargo, me interesa hacerlo con el código más básico posible. Cualquier orientación, como siempre, es muy apreciada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en `sum+= i.isdigit()` ya que estas sumando la salida del método `str.isdigit` y no el entero, en realidad cuentas los caracteres que son dígitos (las veces que `str.isdigit` retorna `True`).

[`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) retorna `True` (1) si todos los caracteres de una cadena son digitos y la cadena tiene al menos un carácter. En caso contrario retorna `False` (0).

> **Nota:** `str.isdigit` considera también como dígitos superíndices y subíndices  numéricos (³), junto a otros caracteres como ➍ o ፮ (6 en caracteres etíopes). Esto causaría un fallo en el casting a entero por lo que sería oportuno solo validar caracteres en el rango 0-9 usando `str.isdecimal`.

Necesitas convertir aquellos caracteres que sean dígitos en enteros para poder sumarlos como tales. en caso contrario sumarias (concatenarías) cadenas. Para ello simplemente hay que hacer `int(string)`.

El código debería ser:

```
def sum_c(x):
    sum=0
    for i in x:
        if i.isdecimal():
            sum+= int(i)
    return sum
```

---

```
>>> sum_c("1234afkñl21")
13
```

Usando un generador y `sum` podrías hacer algo más eficiente:

```
def sum_c(x):
    return sum(int(c) for c in x if c.isdecimal())
```

Comment: Gracias. Quiero ver si entendí bien: if i.isdigit() "aisla" los dígitos de la cadena y después int(i) los "transforma" a enteros para después sumarlos. ¿Es correcto el razonamiento?

Comment: @AlejandroCarrera si esa es la idea más u menos. He editado la respuesta mencionado esto. Un saludo.